# What is the Difference Between `apt-get purge` and `apt-get remove`?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, purge

Is there any difference between

```
sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
```

and

```
sudo apt-get remove <package-name>
```

?

I often see people recommend one or the other.

In other words, what does `apt-get purge` remove that `apt-get remove` doesn't?

Comment: Related (since `apt` is similar, but an alternative to, `apt-get`): https://askubuntu.com/questions/936810/apt-remove-vs-purge

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard perhaps "how can I be a decent, considerate and polite human being?" should be _your_ first question. We expect users here to be civil to each other and your comment is way out of line. Maybe take a walk next time you are frustrated instead of taking your frustration out on innocent posters of 9-year-old questions. If you can't say something constructive, please say nothing at all. That sort of comment is not welcome here.

Comment: How was my comment "uncivil".  And "learn to read the docs first and *then* (docs can often be <censored>) ask question" is the foundational constructive answer.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard "RTFM" is uncivil by definition, you know what the F stands for. Next, coming to a question that was asked 9 years ago and leaving a comment basically saying "go read the manual, you idiot" is useless beyond belief. It's been 9 years! An answer might still be useful, but a condescending, rude and uninformative comment, not so much. Finally, to add insult to injury, this particular OP has spent the intervening 9 years being very active on this site and learning a lot about Linux. They were even a mod for several years! It's safe to assume that they have read the manual by now.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

As the [`man apt-get` page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-get.8.html) says:

> **remove** - remove is identical to install except that packages are removed instead of installed. Note that removing a package **leaves its configuration files on the system**. If a plus sign is appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be installed instead of removed.
>
> **purge** - purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (**any configuration files are deleted too**).

This of course, does not apply to packages that hold configuration files inside the user's home folder (e.g. `/home/Ubuntu_User`), these files will not be touched ( [Why does "Purge" not remove everything related to an app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176685/why-does-purge-not-remove-everything-related-to-an-app?rq=1) )

So for example, if you were to `purge` Chrome, Firefox, Kodi, or any other that holds some configuration files inside your `/home` folder, these configuration files will stay there.

On the other hand, if you were to install Apache, squid, MySQL, or any other services similar that save their configuration files in `/etc`, these configuration files will be deleted if you use `purge`.

Comment: Purge can be used on a meta package to remove it, while leaving the underlying package intact.  If you want to upgrade the base system without affecting postgres, you can apt-get purge the postgres meta package and then upgrading from Debian 7- Debian 8 will leave your postgres version untouched.

Answer (score 45):

An excerpt from [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187891/88802) on another question:

> - `apt-get remove packagename`
>   will remove the binaries, but not the configuration or data files of the package `packagename`.
> - `apt-get purge packagename`, or 
>   `apt-get remove --purge packagename`
>    will remove about *everything* regarding the package
>     `packagename`, [...]
>    Particularly useful
>     when you want to 'start all over' with an application because you
>     messed up the configuration.

Answer (score 27):

**`apt-get purge`** removes configuration files, while **`apt-get remove`** does not.

Comment: This answer could be in more detail.