# How to list what installed and rollback apt-get BY DATE AND TIME?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I have installed two packages (`xrdp` and `ubuntu-desktop`) on my server release and it cause isntallation of numerous packages by dependencies, including even sphinx speech recognition. If I would know these two packages are so heavy, I would not install them.

What can I do now?

How to revert all installations done last hour? Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure if this may help, but /var/log/apt has some history files that show recent installs. I'm not sure how often it's updated, but at least on my machine it shows updates and installs i did for today

Answer (score 0):

Assuming neither `xrdp` nor `ubuntu-desktop` was actually installed before, you can remove them and all the packages that were automatically installed to satisfy their dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get purge xrdp ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

Or in one step:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xrdp ubuntu-desktop
```

[Here's an example of what that looks like.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8488239/)

This does not select by date and time, but I suspect that's not really necessary (or helpful) toward solving this particular problem. The packages you don't want were installed because they were needed for  [`xrdp`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xrdp) and [`ubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-desktop). (Probably mostly for `ubuntu-desktop`, which is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) whose purpose is to cause lots of stuff to be installed.)

So removing them and autoremoving their automatically installed dependencies is probably the most correct and elegant solution.

(*Just* running `sudo apt-get purge` on the two manually installed packages [would *not* automatically cause the dependencies to be removed](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8488265/). The only difference between the `remove` and `purge` actions is that `purge` [deletes systemwide configuration files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove) of the packages it removes.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
sudo apt-get purge xrdp ubuntu-desktop
```

Which will remove those packages and all the dependencies that they installed, though be careful with purging ubuntu-desktop, not sure why you would want to do that...

Comment: Is it possible to uninstall by date and time?

Comment: No, it didn't work at all. It uninstalled only that 2 packages. `X11` remained installed. It is server, no need to have `X11`

Comment: @Termhn The `purge` action does not also uninstall dependencies (though [they will be purged too if `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` is run afterwards](http://askubuntu.com/a/531949/22949).)

Comment: Hm, thought it did. Learn something new every day. Thanks @EliahKagan