# Can't Update or Upgrade 'dpkg returned with error code (2)'

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I realize that this may be a duplicate question but it seems like dpkg is returning error (2) for multiple different reasons. When trying to update and upgrade packages I am returned with:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 50819 package 'openssh-client':
value for 'Conffiles' field has malformatted line '/etc/ssh/moduli'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have tried multiple things from different questions of the same nature and they have yielded no results, any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like `openssh` may be corrupt, but I'm not completely sure. See if running `sudo apt-get remove openssh-client` fixes anything.

Comment: @Zacharee1 It returned with the exact same error code from before.

Comment: @IllümInteractive, if you still have same issue, add the output of `grep -A 45  "Package: openssh-client" /var/lib/dpkg/status` to the question . I want to see that bad line, so we can remove it of fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file of `openssh` are corrupted, you have to remove it and reinstall.

Use `sudo apt-get purge` instead of `sudo apt-get remove`.

You can find more information about this here: [What is the Difference Between `apt-get purge` and `apt-get remove`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove)