# UnInstalling Koha-common brings errors

Tags: 14.04

I initially installed Koha from packages using instructions on [this site](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages#Appendix_A:_Named-based_vs._IP-based_installations).

I decided to uninstall it, I used `apt-get remove koha-common` then I deleted the install dir which was (`/usr/share/koha/`) permanently. Later when I used `apt-get purge koha-common` it brings this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package koha-common (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned exit status 1
Error: /usr/share/koha/bin/koha-functions.sh not present
...
dpkg: error while cleaning up...
```

This error tends to persist when I try to re-install. As a result I have not been able to re-install. Please, anybody with a solution or a hack on how to overcome this!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Koha issue. Please read [`apt` manual page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-get.8.html) (similar to `apt-get`) running `man apt`. You should expect to receive an error about a file not being present on a folder you just deleted. To remove completely Koha should be enough to

```
sudo apt purge koha-common
```

`apt remove` (and with `apt-get`) [is different](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove) will leave configuration files of the package (again, that's on manual page).

As [said here](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages#Uninstall_Instructions) remove first all Koha instance.