# apt remove vs purge

Tags: apt, package-management, purge

I see `sudo apt remove package_name` and `sudo apt purge package_name`,
but what is the difference? is one safer than the other or does one remove packages installed by that package?

Comment: @daisy Very related, yes. Duplicate? No. `apt` and `apt-get` are not the same program.

Comment: @Mast but accepted answers are the same.

Comment: The duplicate candidate just got closed as a duplicate of "how do I completely remove applications" or something like that (on my phone sorry)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can read the manual of apt with

```
man apt
```

On **line 35** you will find the following

```
       Removing a package removes all packaged data, but leaves usually
       small (modified) user configuration files behind, in case the
       remove was an accident. Just issuing an installation request for
       the accidentally removed package will restore its function as
       before in that case. On the other hand you can get rid of these
       leftovers by calling purge even on already removed packages. Note
       that this does not affect any data or configuration stored in your
       home directory.
```

So in short: 
`remove` leaves some config files behind where `purge` does not. And you can even use purge if later you want to delete those config files.

Answer (score 6):

The manpage of `apt-get` (run `man apt-get` to see this) says:

```
remove
    remove is identical to install except that packages are removed instead of installed. Note that removing a
    package leaves its configuration files on the system. If a plus sign is appended to the package name (with
    no intervening space), the identified package will be installed instead of removed.

purge
    purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are
    deleted too).
```

In a nutshell, `remove` keeps the configuration files while `purge` removes them. Both are safe, but which one to pick depends on whether you want to remove configurations.

Comment: `apt-get` is not necessarily the same as `apt`, as I understand from this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get
However in this case it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @urben Oh yeah I know.

Comment: Ok. Well I was about to mark the question as a duplicate, but since they are not necessarily the same and didn't find it the question for `apt`, I looked it up myself to check.

Comment: If you consider `apt` a prettier but less stable upgrade to `apt-get` then it could be considered a duplicate question. Can you imagine if every single question in AU about `apt-get` was reworded and reposted as `apt`?