# Which version of NVIDIA Binary driver to choose in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I want to install NVIDIA graphics driver in ubuntu 16.04. In order to do that I went to Additional Drivers tabs in software & Updates, but there are multiple options available and I don't have an idea which one to choose.

- Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 415.27 from nvidia-415 (open
  source)
- Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 430.64 from nvidia-430
  (open source)
- Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 410.78 from
  nvidia-410 (open source)
- Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.130
  from nvidia-384 (proprietary)
- Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display
  driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)
- Using NVIDIA
  binary driver - version 418.56 from nvidia-418 (open source)

Is this a complete random process? I mean, how do I know which one is the best option for me? Do I have to install every driver and check which one works for me?

Laptop Specifications:

- Series : Predator Helios 300
- Model Number : G3-572
- Graphic Processor
  : NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050Ti
- OS Architecture :
  64 bit

Is there any alternate best practice to install NVIDIA driver? I would really appreciate someone's advice/guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose: Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.130 from nvidia-384 (proprietary)

That one is by Nvidia and has great performance. Unlike AMD, Nvidia open source drivers aren't nearly as good and proprietary. Blame Nvidia for not sharing with the community and thank AMD for providing support to open source community.

You can also grab the latest recommended driver straight from Nvidia. That driver was released in 2018. If you're gaming, get latest from Nvidia. Also take a look at the older drivers, but newer that 2018. In the past I've had difficulty getting Nvidia drivers to work, but Ubuntu 18.04 fixed most of those issues and newer kernels have better support.

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/159360/en-us

Ubuntu 16.04 reaches End of Life in April 2021 so you have plenty of time. Consider installing HWE for best driver support via kernel.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: When I am installing any of the above drivers, I am facing infinite login loop issue.

Comment: Try cleaning your system. sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*              
https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove

Comment: Thanks, will try this.