# Kubuntu shows on boot instead ubuntu

Tags: boot, apt, uninstall

I tried Kubuntu 20.04 by installing with `$ sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop`. It worked very well but I wanted to switch back to ubuntu 20.04, so I used these to remove kubuntu:

`$ sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop` and

`$ sudo apt-get autoremove`

After I reboot the desktop switched back but on the boot it didn`t.
Somebody can help me about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the boot splash screen...

In `terminal`...

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` # change to ubuntu splash

`sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth` # change to ubuntu text

`sudo update-initramfs -u` # update ramdisk

`reboot`

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Comment: @damics.mark Great news!

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt purge kubuntu-desktop` will purge the system of the app and any *system* configuration files.

Then, remove and user-specific configuration files for Kubuntu manually.  [Package management doesn't do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove) because it didn't create those files (they are created by the programs) and it doesn't know whether they are still in use, for example by a version of the program you have installed without the package manager or because your are using a shared home in a network or multi boot environment.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn`t work

Comment: Did you check for user-specific configuration files and then reboot?