# What is the Difference Between "apt autoremove --purge" & "apt purge --autoremove"

Tags: apt, package-management

As I understand, `apt autoremove --purge` purges ([as opposed to only removing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove)) all packages eligible for `autoremove`.

But I cannot grasp how `apt purge --autoremove` would be any different. I can't think of any room for different behavior.

Are these two equivalent? Both cmds run fine:

[image]

Comment: The purge command is a part of the apt autoremove command. You have to put them in order to be able to run the command... Autoremove is a sub-command of apt, and --purge is a sub-command of autoremove. You have to call the first sub command before running the last sub-command. If you do them in the wrong order, it won't work. Sub command isn't really a thing, but you know what I mean by it, right?

Comment: I get that the cmds are structurally different, but I am concerned about how they are, if at all, behaviorally different.

Comment: I think that I explained that... If the commands are in the wrong order, they won't work. That is how they are behaviorally different. `apt purge --autoremove` is in the wrong order, as `--purge` is a sub-part of `autoremove`.

Comment: Does reading `man apt` not help?

Comment: they both seem to work though https://i.imgur.com/53gIdxL.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None: the end result will be the same. Both `apt autoremove --purge` and `apt purge --autoremove` will cause orphan dependencies, i.e., packages automatically installed and not anymore required by any other package, to be removed, including their system wide configuration files ("purge").

Without the options, they will behave differently. `apt autoremove` will do an autoremove, whereas `apt purge` will do nothing because no package was specified.

Comment: an even more concise form of the recursive purge exists, `apt autopurge`, but [remains undocumented for now](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/761079/85414).