# How to do a clean package install after accidentally interrupting the build-essential package installation?

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, cleanup

I was installing the [build essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/build-essential) package through command line using:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

After almost 4 minutes and reaching 87% completion, I mistakenly pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and a black screen appeared and I had to reboot.

On reboot, I removed all the files using `apt-get remove build-essential` and again tried to reinstall it.

Now the package install takes **only 5 seconds** and prompts me with the message:

```
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 159 not upgraded.

Need to get 0 B/5,614 B of archives.

After this operation, 37.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.

(Reading database ... 195397 files and directories currently installed.)

Unpacking build-essential (from .../build-essential_11.6ubuntu5_i386.deb) ...

Setting up build-essential (11.6ubuntu5) ...
```

and the process was finished.

I want to clean uninstall everything and go through the
installation process of that 50MB again. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any downloaded packages will likely have been cached, which would speed up the second install dramatically. Plus the dependencies of build-essential which completed installing will not be automatically installed again.

dpkg and apt are very robust tools and will very likely have coped fine with unexpected reboot. If you're really paranoid, however, you can use debsums to check the integrity of almost all installed packages (all those with checksums available) - you may need to install debsums, and you probably want to run it with -c or -s.) Also, "dpkg -C" and "apt-get check" will verify the general integrity of the installed package set.

Comment: If you really want to uninstall all the dependencies that were installed, you could find the package names from /var/log/dpkg.log .. a bit of playing with grep and awk would automate the process!

Answer (score 0):

Black screen appears only because of  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and  not because of `build-essential` package.

[How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)