# Uninstall Apache2 from terminal on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: apache2, uninstall

How can I uninstall Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04, from the terminal? I don't know the commands.

Comment: `sudo apt-get sudo apt-get remove apache2`. Please refer here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This would do what you want

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2*
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to remove apache use:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

Though if you don't intend to reinstall at some point and would like to remove all of apache's configuration files then use:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```