# Completely REMOVE and REINSTALL vlc on my system?

Tags: vlc

I am using a Ubuntu 15.10 machine and everything was just fine until yesterday..when I decided it might be cool to run kde on my system, so I installed plasma and that's when things started to get bad.I logged in to plasma, and tried to play a video using vlc, and I there was something weird.Even in fullscreen, the video occupied only about a quarter of the screen, and I was unable to fix it.So I logged out of plasma and back to unity, and the problem was still there.Since then I have tried many possible solutions without avail.I tried reinstalling vlc,using synaptic to remove vlc and reinstall, using purge to remove vlc, and finally that issue is gone but there is new one. Now vlc display audio in one instance and audio in another. The instance with audio has the menu bar. I tried changing setting to allow only one instance but it didn't fix the problem. I really want to use vlc. I want to get vlc just as it was when I first installed i it. Any suggestions?

Update: I just discovered that when I check integrate video in interface, there is only one instance, but the previous issue returns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you completely remove a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)

Answer (score 6):

In a terminal, run:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

Done.

Comment: Just tried it, same issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Close all instances of vlc `sudo killall vlc` and check it with `ps -lef|grep vlc`
2. try to remove configuration files in your home directory `find ~ -iname "*vlc*" -exec rm -ri {} \;` it is with confirmation so tell him to remove them or not...

Configuration files are located into `$(HOME)/.config/vlc/vlcrc` (v0.9.0 and above), `$(HOME)/.vlc/vlcrc` (v0.8 and older)
according to [vlc configuration documentation](http://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html#Config)

Comment: Deleted all config files, same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My fixed it was

sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get autoremove

cd /

find vlc (as --purge does not always remove everything as its supposed to) 
then delete any remaining files.

Rerun sudo apt-get autoremove,  not necessary,  but why not. 
Reinstall vlc

In my case --purge removed only the files in my home directory,  leaving files in /bin and in another location that I don't remember.

Answer (score -3):

locate or find vlc from terminal and than delete all files from respective folders

Comment: This is a really really bad advice. That will break the system.