# VLC Player does not display bold subtitles/font (regardless which font is selected)

Tags: fonts, vlc, subtitle

When I was using Windows, VLC was able to display any font properly: Regular and bold. But when I started using Ubuntu and used the pre-installed VLC player, only the normal font variant was displayed all the time. Changing the settings did not work and [reinstalling VLC](https://askubuntu.com/a/716768/845469) made no difference.

Other programs like gedit and Libre Office and even TeX, however, work perfectly fine. They can deal with all the installed fonts properly.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

1. Open the `Tools` menu and click on `Preferences` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open it.
2. Now, take a look at the corner on the bottom left. Set `Show settings` from `Stimple` to `All`.
3. Scroll down to `Video -> Subtitles / OSD` and select `Text renderer`.
4. Check `Force bold` and click `Save`.
5. Restart VLC and everything should just work fine.