# Kubuntu 16.10 linux headers problem

Tags: kubuntu, 16.10, linux-headers

Kubuntu 16.10
Asus N750J

Hello, here repotyig  problem.
I try to update....:

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for user: 
Get:1 http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http: //ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                           
Hit:3 http: //de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                        
Hit:4 http: //repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                               
Hit:5 http: //de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease                                                                
Hit:6 http: //ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                       
Hit:7 http: //de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-proposed InRelease                                                           
Hit:8 http: //download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian yakkety InRelease 
Fetched 102 kB in 1s (66.7 kB/s)
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I try it and...

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
Setting up linux-headers-4.8.0-34-generic (4.8.0-34.36) ... 
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d. 
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-34-generic
```

when I do it this happen, and stay there forever, i try to close it and run another command and wont let me try another command, i have to restart the computer, also if i try to do it in a more grafic way like...:

```
software-properties-gtk

(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Cannot set locale: unsupported locale setting

(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:68:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:69:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-y is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:73:46: The style property GtkScrolledWindow:scrollbars-within-bevel is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:76:30: The style property GtkExpander:expander-size is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory aplets/64 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory aplets/64 of theme breeze-dark has no size field
(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkNotebook    
(software-properties-gtk:3628): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkNotebook
```

Opens the "software & updates" preferences and when you configure it and close it, it self update and shows a window:

The information about available software is out-of-date

To install software and updates from newly added or changed sources, you have to reload the information about available software.

You need a working internet connection to continue.

I click reload and shows:

```
Setting up linux-headers-4.8.0-34-generic (4.8.0-34.36) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-34-generic
```

and again.. stay there forever with out doing nothing

could you guys tell me some possible solution, im lost here.

build log in: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-367/367.57/build/    :

Kbuild file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23911754/

.log file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23911773/

Comment: When you run `dpkg --configure -a` how long is "forever"? It can easily take 5–15 minutes to build *each* kernel module known to your DKMS setup. Could you please include the output of `ps axjf` so we can get a better idea what's going on?

Comment: i leaved it the whole night running and no answer

Comment: Done like you did, with systax bash.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/23911421/

sorry I respond later, iI can only do it at home and I'm going trough mobil wifi.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. You can delete the comments with the incomplete pasties now. DPKG is clearly stuck during the build process of the Nvidia kernel module via DKMS. There should be a build log somewhere in `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-367/367.57/build/`. Could you please put a copy of that into your question (either in-line or through a pastie link)?

Comment: sorry againg, im very new with this.

I found a file name Kbuild: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23911754/

And the only .log file is this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23911773/

Comment: Nothing noteworthy there except that the log file doesn't contain much at all. The `KBuild` file is actually a file with build instructions not a log file. The only idea I have right now is to remove the Nvidia driver package with `dpkg -r nvidia-367`, configure pending packages with `dpkg --configure -a` and reinstall the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I unistalles successfully the driver, purged packages, aplly sudo apt auto remove, reload the system, update and upgrade and all works fine. when i reinstal the nvidia drivers and find the same error will report it here.

thanks a lot for your help and your time (y)

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the Nvidia driver package with dpkg -r nvidia-367
   (you must select other driver in order to uninstall)
2. configure pending packages with dpkg --configure -a
3. purged packages: [How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)
4. update and upgrade: sudo apt-get update  and sudo apt-get upgrade