# Trying to install spyder3, but getting spyder2

Tags: apt, repository, spyder

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04.

When I try to install spyder3 from the repositories using

```
apt-get install spyder3
```

It installs spyder2 for python3.5. so I get the splash screen, the interface and the configuration folder as same as the spyder2.

How do I install spyder3?

Comment: Please post the command you used...

Comment: I just used sudo apt install spyder3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to install [spyder3 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=spyder3&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) you must first [enable the universe repository.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) Once that step is completed you will be able to install the spyder3 package which currently actually provides 2.3.0 with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install spyder3`

**Note:** If you wish to eliminate the spyder2 configuration files as well as the package you may wish to [backup](https://askubuntu.com/a/586172/225694) to avoid any unintended consequences and then purge the spyder2 package with `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove spyder`

**To obtain the latest version of spyder (currently 3.1.4)**

**If you use anaconda:**

```
conda update qt pyqt
conda update spyder
```

**Only** If you **don't use anaconda**

```
pip install -U spyder
```

If you use anaconda the pip command could break your installation. This is of small concern if you follow my advice about creating a backup and a potentially large problem if you don't.

Sources:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=spyder3&searchon=names

[How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

[How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases

Comment: I'm testing this and posting the results soon. I already imagined that it was a repository issue, or detail.

Comment: Actually, I just checked and the universe repository is already enabled, and I'm installing spyder from there. In fact, if i run "apt-cache policy spyder3"  I get 

spyder3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.3.8+dfsg1-1build1
  Version table:
     2.3.8+dfsg1-1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages

Comment: Universe is enabled? Then you can skip that step. Yes, Installed (none) means it is not installed.  Did you attempt installation as described in my answer?  The package version available that you are getting as a Candidate matches the package version shown in the package search link at the top of my answer for spyder3 so that looks correct.

Comment: Yes, I did. At the moment I issued the "apt-cache policy spyder3", I already have unninstalled spyder. I tried to install again just before posting this, and the result was the same, I got Spyder2.

Comment: That's odd. What's the output of `dpkg -l spyder3` ?

Comment: Ahh, It appears we've been victims of rounding. 2.8.3 is what was released in the spyder3 package. Editing answer.

Comment: @IsaacCurvelo Updated answer.

Comment: I didn't understand. What do you mean by victims of rounding? Did you found out what the error is?

Comment: I understood that the spyder 2.8.3 is what you get from the spyder3 package. But in other OS (ubuntu gnome 16.04) I could install spyder3 out of the box with the command "sudo apt-get install spyder 3"

Comment: I finnaly managed to resolve it. You were right. The version of spyder in pip is up to date! Thanks!

Comment: @IsaacCurvelo I'm glad we got it sorted! I'm always [eager to help!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16264/are-we-truly-eager-to-help)