# Uninstall psensor

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, psensor

I've used this post as a guideline: [How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)

More precisely i did in order:

```
sudo apt-get purge psensor

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Is there anything else i should do to have psensor completely removed from my system (Ubuntu 16.04)?

Comment: No, why do you think anything else is needed?

Comment: @ByteCommander from the mentioned post: [..] This does not remove non-systemwide configuration files. Specifically, it does not remove user-specific configuration:

    It does not remove the configuration files and directories located in users' home directories (or in the .config subdirectory of their home directories), created by the software the package provides.
        If these files/folders are not stored in .config, they usually start with a . themselves. Either way, you can see them with ls by using the -a or -A flag, and you can se ...

Comment: @ZenoRaiser that refers to files you create yourself that are support by a piece of software.

Comment: There might be a hidden `.psensor` folder in your home directory. Delete it if you desire to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commands to completely remove Psensor in your question are correct. Alternatively you can combine both commands in a single line like this:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove psensor
```