# Does "apt autoremove --purge <package>" also remove configuration files for the related packages that are removed?

Tags: apt, package-management

I assume the below command does the following (please correct me if I am wrong):

> I want to remove the package nginx and the related configuration
>   files. I also want to remove any related package dependencies (that
>   are not used by any other package on the system)

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge nginx
```

---

**Question**

Does it also remove the configuration files for the related package(s) (dependencies) that are removed from the system?

Comment: Hi, I think your question has already been answered. See [How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer : **Yes**, but *not* every file related to package is deleted as purge doesn't remove data stored by packages inside the home directory or other special directories.

By Standard definition of Purge:-

> **Purge -** Purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged. Purge meaning that any configuration files are
> deleted too.