# Footprint of installing and uninstalling a program on Ubuntu

Tags: system, aptitude

Just a quick question. You know how in Windows, because of poorly-written programs, sometimes installing and uninstalling a program will leave records in the Windows Registry or AppData folder of a user? Will that happen in Ubuntu if I install and uninstall a program too?

As far as I am aware, Ubuntu doesn't really have a registry (all data is stored in files), and using the `purge` option in Aptitude is supposed to "completely" remove all files related to a program (does it always work?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `purge` option will remove all system-wide configuration files. It will NOT remove any configuration or data files stored in your home directory, nor will it remove packages that were installed as dependencies. For more information, please see the top answer here: [How can you completely remove a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)