# sudo ls -lRa . | grep command

Tags: command-line, package-management, uninstall

I am new to Linux, trying to clean my system after deleting a package 'thunderbird'.

I use command `sudo ls -lRa . | grep thunderbird` to find all the remaining config files and other leftover files to remove them from my system.

This command is very useful and helps me a lot to locate the files related to a specific package. I have already deleted all the directories related to thunderbird, but when I run `sudo ls -lRa . | grep thunderbird` command, this is what I am seeing now:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kao kao 75786 bal.  16 01:26 appimagekit_206c725ecb426eabc4dcda2a204bf247_thunderbird.png
-rw-------  1 kao kao  140 bal.  17 16:48 thunderbird[2].desktop
-rw-------  1 kao kao  140 bal.  17 16:48 thunderbird[3].desktop
-rw-------  1 kao kao  140 bal.  17 16:50 thunderbird[4].desktop
-rw-------  1 kao kao  140 bal.  17 16:53 thunderbird[5].desktop
-rw-------  1 kao kao  140 bal.  17 16:53 thunderbird[6].desktop
-rw-------  1 kao kao  140 bal.  17 16:29 thunderbird.desktop
```

What are those files, how to locate them and remove them?

Comment: `find . -name '*thunderbird*'` would likely be a better way to find the files

Comment: Please clarify: is _cleaning config + leftovers_ the goal ? Or just context to the question _how to find and remove specific files_ ? [Edit] title to describe the actual problem 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to locate them and remove them?

One way to do it would be using the command `find`

```
sudo find / -iname '*thunderbird*'
```

Like this you will parse all the file system and will see every element that contains the expression "thunderbird"

Alternativly we have **fd-find** in our repositroy which is faster then find (because it uses multithread) 
 It is not installed by default, you can install it with apt

```
sudo apt install fd-find
```

Syntax is lighter and output is colorized

```
fd thunderbird /
```

You can also use locate

```
locate thunderbird
```

To remove a file use the `rm` command

Comment: Thanks! 

`sudo find / -iname '*thunderbird*'` is a really strong command! 

why do I get different results with

`sudo find / -iname '*thunderbird*'` 

and

`locate thunderbird`

Comment: Hi, @shiu'sho, why you need `sudo` for this operation?

Comment: Hi, @kcdtv, we can pipe the output of `find` to `xargs ... rm`, or we can add to `find` the options `-delete` or `-exec rm {} +` in order to delete all files found.

Comment: @ shiu'sho: locate works diferently, it parses a data base created on system startup while find realy parse the system in the moment you execute it. That why you may have some elements not found by locate   @ pa4080: if you don't use sudo you won't get the pathes outside your user file system. Thanks for the tips to do everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't need to do it by hand. Package manager will take care of removing system-wide configs of given package using `purge` action or when providing `--purge` for `remove` action

```
sudo apt purge thunderbird
```

From `apt-get(8)`:

> **purge**: purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any
>     configuration files are deleted too).
>
> **--purge**:
>              Use purge instead of remove for anything that would be removed. An asterisk ("*") will
>              be displayed next to packages which are scheduled to be purged.  remove --purge is
>              equivalent to the purge command. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Purge.

If you still feel like looking up file by somehow matching with name use `find` as suggested in other answers; it will output full path of the matched file.

Comment: As I read OPs question, you sensed the issue incl. suitable solution  Could the _purge_ also be done way after `apt remove` ?

Comment: @hc_dev Yes, there's a separate package state called `config-files` in `dpkg`: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg.1.en.html. Also, I was not right about **user** configs, they are not deleted by apt as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package, only system-wide configuration is purged, so editing that part. (The .desktop files OP mentions probably _will_ be handled by `purge`)

Answer (score 0):

Desktop files are analog  to Start Menu shortcuts in Windows. Those files register some command or application in the system. Those files define the inicialization parameters of a application or command.

They are stored in `/usr/share/applications` to every user or `~/.local/share/applications` if its only acessible to one user.

Exemple:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Nome do aplicativo de exemplo
Comment=Um aplicativo de exemplo
Exec=aplicativo
Icon=aplicativo.png
Terminal=false
```

> [Desktop Entry]

```
First line and header of the file.
```

> Type=Application

```
Tells the enviroment that this desktop file belongs to a application. May also be a Link or Directory.
```

> Encoding=UTF-8

```
Describe the coding of the file.
```

> Name=Example Name

```
Application names for the menu and any launcher.
```

> Comment=A exemple of an app

```
Describe the  application ("tooltip").
```

> Exec=aplicativo

```
The shell command that start the application. 
May have arguments.
```

> Icon=application.png

```
Icon's file.
```

> Terminal=false

```
Describe if the application must beexecuted ina terminal.
```

Souce: https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.pt_BR

Answer (score 0):

When you want to remove user specific configuration files and application data:

Your configuration files are located in the **~/.thunderbird** folder, where **~** means your home folder.

You can remove with the following command:

```
rm -fr ~/.thunderbird
```